# Python dictionary value assignment from variable

Tags: python

I have this routine:

```
def _get_files_download_list(self, proj):
    tmp = {}

    # get the global file download list
    global_files = self.config['projects']['global']['server_group']['global']['file_download']

    for k in proj['server_group'].keys():
        # create the array for each server group
        # add the global stuff to each server group
        tmp_keys = global_files
        try:
            if 'file_download' in proj['server_group'][k]:
                # loop the server groups and add the file_download to that array
                for key in proj['server_group'][k]['file_download']:
                    # this way if something overrides the global, so be it, but the global is added to everything
                    tmp_keys[key] = proj['server_group'][k]['file_download'][key]
        except KeyError as e:
            pass

        if len(tmp_keys) > 0:
            tmp[k] = tmp_keys
    return tmp
```

the problem is at the end of the routine, the different `tmp[k]` values all have the same value.  I suspect the problem has to do with the way python links variables to the dictionary in memory. im thinking python assigns a pointer to an object location in memory instead of creating a new instance of the object on the `tmp_keys = global_files` line.  If im correct, whats the syntax to create a new instance of the object instead of just updating the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
import copy
tmp_keys = copy.copy(global_files)
```

Depending on what kind of data is in global_files, it may only pass in a reference.

Comment: global_files is a dictionary if that helps `"file_download": {
                        "remote_log_file": "logs.tar.gz"
                    },` is the value its grabbing if it helps

Comment: IIRC correctly, most iterables like list, dictionary, numpy arrays etc... will pass by reference when you put them in a new dictionary or list.